# Next.js: How to make only one input field inline editable when every tag checks whether its isEdit state is true or false

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-state, conditional-rendering

I have some tags that display text they conditionally render `<input />` tags by checking whether the `edit` state is `true` or `false`. When `true`, instead of showing text, I render an `<input />` tag to make inline edit.

Everything works well. The only problem is, when one `<button>` tag changes the `edit` state to true, then, instead of showing input field for editing where **Edit** was clicked, every tag renders their input field.

How do I limit this rendering of input field for only those tags from where the `edit` state was changed by the **Edit** button click?

My code:

```
const [ edit, setEdit ] = useState(false);
const isEdit = edit;

<div>
    <p>{ !isEdit ? (<span>Email: {userProfile.email} <button onClick={e=>setEdit(!edit)}>Edit</button></span>) : (<span>Email: 
    <input type="text" placeholder="email"
          name="email"  onChange={e=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
    <button type="submit" onClick={addUserEmail}>Save</button></span>
     )}
</p>
<p>About: { !isEdit ? (<span> {userProfile.about} <button onClick={e=>setEdit(!edit)}>Edit</button>        
     </span>) :
    (<span>
           <input type="text" placeholder="about"
                 name="about"  onChange={e=>setAbout(e.target.value)}
           />
            <button type="submit" onClick={addUserAbout}>Save</button>
     </span>)                            
    )}
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Two different edit-states don't work?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions, but the cleanest way would probably be to separate those editable fields into their own component since each of them has its own state.

For example, you can create a generic EditableField component similar to this one:

```jsx
    function EditableComponent({defaultIsEditing = false, renderText, renderInput}) {
       const [ isEditing, setIsEditing ] = useState(defaultIsEditing);

       if(!isEditing){
          //Non-edit mode
          return (<span> {renderText()} <button onClick={e=>setEdit(!edit)}>Edit</button></span>);
       }

       //Edit mode
       return renderInput();
    }
```

Then use it as this:

```jsx
<div>
      <EditableComponent
         renderText={() => <>Email: {userProfile.email}</>}
         renderInput={() => (<span>Email: 
                              <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"  onChange={e=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                               <button type="submit" onClick={addUserEmail}>Save</button>
                             </span>)}
      />

     {/* ...repeat for all fields */}
</div>
```

This solution ensures that you don't repeat the same logic over and over. With two fields you might be okay just making two state variables (e.g. isEdit1, isEdit2), but the more you add the more cumbersome it will become.

Another alternative would be to store the name of the input you're editing as state, this will ensure that only one field is edited at a time, but you need to take care of saving old fields when starting to edit new ones

Comment: Why are `renderText` and `renderInput` are callables?

Comment: no reason in that particular case, you can make them non-functions too